# xlwings - can't find xlwings32.dll

Tags: python, xlwings

I originally had an older version of Anaconda and Python2.7 on my machine, and xlwings worked great.  I recently uninstalled Anaconda / Python (via window's add remove programs...), and installed the newest version of Anaconda with Python 3.6 (which includes xlwings).

I went back to my excel sheets, and suddenly it can't find the xlwings dll.  I've checked:

1. The DLL is in the same folder as python.exe
2. My environment variables are correct, and have the python.exe
   folder path in PATH.
3. I can, in Command Line, go to python $, and import xlwings, and
   see its path is in the correct spot...

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Anaconda folder, if you installed xlwings correctly, you'll see the dll files there, but they're named after their version number ie. "xlwings32-11.8.dll"

Change the name of the corresponding file to "xlwings32.dll".

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve the issue by going into the "xlwings" module and replacing any mention of the xlwings dll with the full file location, as in the following image:

[image]

Disclaimer: I've only been using the xlwings package for 2 days so I'm not sure if this is the right method.